# How to add a secret function for application's privacy

Tags: java, android, eclipse, privacy

I've created a SMS application. However, anyone can open my application. What I want to do is to prevent unauthorized access to my application. How could I add a secret function for the privacy of my application.

Thanks.

Comment: Define *unauthorized access*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create logon procedure. For instance during creation of your main Activity - check whether user logged in and if not forward to dialog/activity which will ask to log in